# Можно ли исключить файл из компиляции?

Tags: visual-studio

Иногда бывает потребность, взять какой-нибудь файл кода из другого проекта, как пример какого-то решения и по нему что-то делать, как пример какого-то рабочего решения/алгоритма.

Может не хватать каких-то типов => он не валидный для компиляции.
Можно ли сделать так, что бы я его мог смотреть в Visual Studio, но в тоже время он не мешал компиляции?

P.S Да, можно открыть файл в NotePad++, но там не такая богатая навигация...

Comment: Чтобы читать файл, необязательно его в сам проект добавлять...

Comment: Да... Но в Visual Studio удобная навигация. Например, можно по названию метода прыгнуть в его описание.

Comment: Помню, что-то такое в своё время делал, если добавить `// <auto-generated />` в самом начале файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Для этого нужно в свойствах файла изменить значение свойства «Build Action» с «Compile» на «None».

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого файл не будет компилироваться при сборке.

Такой же вопрос на EN.SO: [How to exclude files from Visual Studio compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219381/how-to-exclude-files-from-visual-studio-compile)

P.S. Имхо, в данном случае проще открыть два экземпляра Visual Studio с разными проектами.